# Object position in world coordinates

Tags: xtk

I have some objects in a scene and I want to know how to get the world coordinates of the object after some rotations.

For example, I used this: `X.matrix.multiplyByVector(X.cube.transform.matrix, 0, 0, 0);` to get the world coordinates at the very begining of the rendering process. The coordinates are `(201.5, -54.5, 102.5)`

Then I make some rotations and then applied the formula again and it display the same coordinates as before even though the object (a cube in this example) is in another place in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of the X.cube.transform.matrix before and after rotation, to see if it get modified?

Moreover if your object is centered on (0, 0, 0) and if you rotate the object around its center (0, 0, 0), the position of the center will still be the same...
In this case you could try with the cube borders.

Does it make sense?

Hope this helps